# php multidimensional array encode and decode json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array what I encode as json and I save it to database. The array looks like

```
 $myarray = array(
    'test'=>array('key1'=>'1',
                  'key2'=>'2',
                  'key3'=>'3'),
    'test2' =>array('key4'=>'1',
                   'key5'=>'<a href="myclass"></a>'
                  )
     );
json_encode($myarray);
```

the saved json in my database looks like

```
{

 "test":  {"key1":"1",
           "key2":"2",
           "key3":"3"
          },
 "test2": {"key4":"1",
           "key5":"<a href ="myclass"></a>"
           }
}
```

**MYSQL save**
`$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET params= '".json_encode($param )."' WHERE id` ='".$key."'";

Than when I retrieve the json string from database and trying to rebuild the array with `json_decode($json, true);` outputs null

Comment: Your php copy & paste looks to be syntactically broken without the right ' s.

Comment: `var_dump($json);` to make sure it really is string you want to decode

Comment: I've been spending on this 2 hours now my nerves are down

Comment: the example above is not copy and paste

Comment: var_dump the json after you got it out of the database

Comment: is returning the json string but maybe one thing can be a problem in this case, I have links in my json string like <a class="tooltip" and this are not escaped

Comment: might be that the escaping in the encoded json breaks when you save it to the DB - how do you do that?

Comment: this is not valid json after your edit. If you are using `stripslashes` before decoding, don't do it. If it is not an issue, use Adminer or phpMyAdmin or any other database management tool to verify that field holds properly escaped quotes, that leaves either wrong method of inserting to database or bad server configuration

Comment: You should escape your links before putting them in your JSON (with addslashes for example)!

Comment: thank you I'm going to try like that

Comment: (if you find something working, answer your own question and mark it as accepted)

Comment: okay it seems like json_encode before saving the data is escaping properly, but when is getting stored in database everything is saved without escapes

Comment: thanks for your help all of you the solution $mysqli->real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize the data rather than storing it as json.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET field='".serialize($myarray)."' WHERE ...";
```

Then when you want to recreate the array, just pull it out of the table and unserialize() it.  It's not human readable in the database; however this technique is fast and works well for storing arrays in the db.  If the data is needed by your js scripts then json_encode() it after you unserialize() it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to use `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` php functions ?

Try:
To update your table:

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET params='".addslashes(json_encode($myarray))."' WHERE id ='".$key."';";
```

to read from table:

```
$sql = "SELECT params FROM my_table WHERE id='".$key."';";
...code to read row...
$myparams = stripslashes($row['params']);
```

also you can try the a custom function for a multidimensional array from php manual called `stripslashes_deep()` see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php (EXAMPLE #2)

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example
$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

print_r($array);

// Output    
Array
(
    [0] => f'oo
    [1] => b'ar
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => fo'o
            [1] => b'ar
        )

)
```